# Compojure - map query parameters with string keys

Tags: clojure, compojure, ring

I know I can map the **query string** as a keyworkd map.

```clj
(defroutes my-routes
  (GET "/" {params :query-params} params))
```

But is there a way do the same with a **string keyed map**?
(*Using Compojure or Ring*)

The point here is not to iterate over the map or use a function, but *create it with string keys by default*.

```clj
{ :a "b" } -> {"a" "b"}
```

Comment: which middleware are you using? I do get a string-keyed map when using `ring.middleware.params`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Compojure 1.5.1 does not parse any query strings by default (by not using any  middleware). However, this might have been different in earlier versions.

```
(require '[compojure.core :refer :all])
(require '[clojure.pprint :refer [pprint]])

(defroutes handler
  (GET "/" x
       (with-out-str (pprint x)))) ;; just a way to receive a pretty printed string response

$ curl localhost:3000/?a=b
{:ssl-client-cert nil,
 :protocol "HTTP/1.1",
 :remote-addr "127.0.0.1",
 :params {},  ;; EMPTY!
 :route-params {},
 :headers
 {"user-agent" "curl/7.47.1", "accept" "*/*", "host" "localhost:3000"},
 :server-port 3000,
 :content-length nil,
 :compojure/route [:get "/"],
 :content-type nil,
 :character-encoding nil,
 :uri "/",
 :server-name "localhost",
 :query-string "a=b",  ;; UNPARSED QUERY STRING
 :body
 #object[org.eclipse.jetty.server.HttpInputOverHTTP 0x6756d3a3 "HttpInputOverHTTP@6756d3a3"],
 :scheme :http,
 :request-method :get}
```

Ring offers the `ring.params.wrap-params` middleware, which parses the query string and creates a hashmap of it under the params-key:

```
(defroutes handler
  (wrap-params (GET "/" x
                 (prn-str (:params x)))))

$ curl localhost:3000/?a=55
{"a" "55"}
```

Additionaly `ring.params.wrap-params` can be used:

```
(defroutes handler
  (wrap-params (wrap-keyword-params (GET "/" x
                                     (prn-str (:params x))))))

$ curl localhost:3000/?a=55
{:a "55"}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about compojure, but you can undo it yourself:

```
(use 'clojure.walk)

(stringify-keys {:a 1 :b {:c {:d 2}}}) 
;=> {"a" 1, "b" {"c" {"d" 2}}}
```

https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.walk/stringify-keys

Comment: or manually: `(defn stringify-keys [m] (->> (seq m) (map #(update % 0 name)) (into {})))`, which does of course not handle nested maps.

Comment: I'm already using `stringfy-keys`. But I think it's inefficient to iterate over a map again after creating it (the keys of the map already got "transformed" to keywords from string on the creation). I want a solution that create the map with string keys by default.